# Unable to trigger function inside controller using AngularJS / jQuery when focussed on last element in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my webpage, when the user focusses on the last `<input>`, I want a set of a `<input>` and a `<select>` added dynamically.

If I do it with `ng-click` on a `<button>`, it works fine but not with `focus` event on the last `<input>`.

```js
var Note = function($scope){
  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.options = [{name: 'x'}, {name: 'y'}];

  $scope.add = function () {
    console.log('adding..');
    $scope.items.push({
      question: "",
      questionPlaceholder: "foo",
    });

    //console.dir($scope.items);
  };

  $scope.add();

  $('input:last-child').on('focus', function(){      // does not work
    console.log('adding elements dynamically');
    $scope.add();
    $scope.$apply();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Note" id='itemsPool'>
    <form ng-submit="submitHandler()">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="text" placeholder="URL" ng-model="item.question">
        <select ng-init="item.type = options[0]" 
                ng-model='item.type' 
                ng-options="option.name for option in options">
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button ng-click='add()'>Add</button> <!-- works! -->
    <span><-- button will be removed eventually</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this?

Is it possible to fix this without using jQuery? How?

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use jquery here? Why not just use angular?

Comment: have you tried with `ng-blur` or `ng-focus` rather?

Comment: @ajmajmajma I am not sure how to do it using angular. :-|

Comment: If you are using a repeat there is a $last

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary To which element should I do that? Its all in `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @RahulDesai check dfsq's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use jQuery like you are using now, use dedicated Angular directives. In your case you need [ngFocus](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus).

This attribute will work well for you:

```
ng-focus="$last && add()"
```

Check the demo:

```js
var Note = function($scope){
  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.options = [{name: 'x'}, {name: 'y'}];

  $scope.add = function () {
    console.log('adding..');
    $scope.items.push({
      question: "",
      questionPlaceholder: "foo",
    });

    //console.dir($scope.items);
  };

  $scope.add();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Note" id='itemsPool'>
    <form ng-submit="submitHandler()">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input type="text" 
               placeholder="URL" 
               ng-model="item.question"
               ng-focus="$last && add()">
        <select ng-init="item.type = options[0]" 
                ng-model='item.type' 
                ng-options="option.name for option in options">
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
    <button ng-click='add()'>Add</button> <!-- works! -->
    <span><-- button will be removed eventually</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with your original approach is that there is nothing to bind focus event to, when you are using jQuery in controller, because `ngRepeat` has not yet rendered anything. Of course, you could workaround it easily with delegated event on the parent container, but you see how clumsy it is getting and not clear.